# Plaid Oauth, bank asking for ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED multiple time a day

Tags: plaid

Is there any longer term Oauth solution?

I used to use OFX for my personal banking info and only had to Oauth once, and it lasted a decade. OFX is no longer supported by my bank and Plaid looks like the best alternative, however, having to do Oauth multiple times a day is not very user friendly. Only accessing balance and transaction info, using products Auth and Transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. To fetch fresh data from a bank, Plaid needs to connect to it on your behalf, which, depending on the bank and your 2fa settings, may require a 2fa token. Plaid is recognized as a trusted connection by some banks, allowing it access once a 2fa token has been given once, but if Plaid is prompting you for 2fa multiple times a day, your bank isn't one of those banks.  Your options to get this to work are really to either change banks or change your 2fa settings (and I recognize that neither of these are great options).

Comment: if I plan on releasing this service to the public then I cant ask a user to switch banks or adjust their bank settings. 

I will experiment with timing on balance queries see if that changes the frequency of 2fa update requests. I will also add a couple more banks I personally use and see how those ones go